# Get all records arranged by maximum number of columns matched

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm looking out for a way to get all records from a table arranged or ordered in such a way that maximum number of columns matched are at top and then further

Example: Table Name(**Vehicle**)

```
Id     Name    VehicleMileage    VehicleAverage    VehicleCC    Gear
1    Vehicle1     30HP@2000         25000             1000        3
2    Vehicle2     30HP@2000         22000             8000        2
3    Vehicle3     20HP@2000         21000             5000        4
4    Vehicle4     60HP@2000         25000             1000        3
5    Vehicle5     70HP@2000         23000             3000        3
```

Over here lets assume the searched parameters are as follows:

```
VehicleMileage: 30HP@2000
VehicleAverage: 25000
VehicleCC: 1000
Gear: 3
```

The queried result would be in following **order**:

```
Vehicle1 (Reason: 4 matched columns)
Vehicle4 (Reason: 3 matched columns)
Vehicle2 (Reason: 1 matched column)
Vehicle5 (Reason: 1 matched column)
Vehicle3 (No matched column)
```

My database is on SQL server.

Comment: FWIW, 'HP@2000' isn't something I'd store - at least not in the same column as the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this

```
SELECT Name + ' (Reason: '+CAST(MatchCount AS VARCHAR)+' matched columns)'
FROM (
        SELECT NAME,(CASE WHEN VehicleMileage ='30HP@2000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                     CASE WHEN VehicleAverage='25000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                     CASE WHEN VehicleCC =1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                     CASE WHEN Gear =3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS MatchCount
       FROM TableName
)t
ORDER BY MatchCount
```

Comment: @Jaydip How we would query the result in desired order.. Your solution do not point to ordering of rows. And the (Reason: 4 matched columns) was just given for explanation